# AndEngine and PathModifier

Tags: android, andengine

Hi there I am designing a game using AndEngine and PhysicsBox2DExtension.

A car driving around in the game and I am using Path to do that. The problem is the car does not hit the obstacles in the game.

Is there a way I can add velocity to the body using path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PathModifier` is not used in conjunction with Box2D, you can't use them both. If you must use Box2D, you can't use the path modifier and you must chage the velocities on your own (You can't use any `EntityModifier`s that move the entity while it is connected to a body in Box2D with a `PhysicsConnector`).